# is it possible to add multiple select statements inside each case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

once more I need some assistance. I have one table called Data and contains cars with color and type.

I have one table called "output" and I want the color number appearing per "CARid" (when type='new') and the total colors per ID.

I tried to do it with "case" but it seems impossible to do it in one sql code. Do I need a temp table and then join?

```
        data    
carID   color   type
1        red    new
2        blue   old
3        red    new
2       green   new
2       blue    new
1       red     old
4       empty   empty


         output 
CarID   NColor  ColorTotal
1        1          2
2        2          3
3        1          1
4        0          0
```

Comment: Your title and your data have nothing to do with each other.  I'm confused.

Comment: Title aside, I don't understand the logic you're trying to write. Including the query that doesn't work might help us understand what you're trying to do more easily than trying to translate it into English.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic aggregation and a case expression should return what I think you are after. But no idea where CarID 4 comes from, it isn't in your sample data.

```
select CarID
    , NColor = sum(case when type = 'new' then 1 end)
    , ColorTotal = count(*)
from Data
group by CarID
```

Comment: If you want to count the number of distinct colors (so that you only count red once, even if there are multiple entries for red), then modify the above to `, ColorTotal = count(DISTINCT color)`

Comment: @LaughingVergil I was thinking the same but this seems to match (except car 4) with what they posted. :) Seems there is likely some normalization issues here for sure.

Comment: I agree @Sean-Lange, which is why I added the comment. They may not have thought all of their requirements through yet, so I drop in comments along the line of "Did you consider this?"  It works great with the developers I work with.